# Python shlex split option that contains RegEx

Tags: python, python-3.x, split, shlex

Lets say I want to give this command
`./maryam -e crawl_pages -d domain.tld -r "a href=\".*"`
and split it.

When I run

```
>>>line = './maryam -e crawl_pages -d domain.tld -r "a href=\".*"'
>>>shlex.split(line)
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shlex.py", line 311, in split
    return list(lex)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shlex.py", line 300, in __next__
    token = self.get_token()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shlex.py", line 109, in get_token
    raw = self.read_token()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shlex.py", line 191, in read_token
    raise ValueError("No closing quotation")
ValueError: No closing quotation
```

What I basically want is to have the -r option for the user to input a regular expression.
The result should look like this

```
['./maryam', '-e', 'crawl_pages', '-d', 'domain.tld', '-r', 'a href=\".*']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign

```py
# XXX BROKEN
line = './maryam -e crawl_pages -d domain.tld -r "a href=\".*"'
```

Python parses the string and parses any backslash escapes, so you end up with no actual backslash in the value of `line`.  You can prevent one layer of backslash parsing by using a raw string instead;

```py
line = r'./maryam -e crawl_pages -d domain.tld -r "a href=\".*"'
```

but if your expected value really should contain a literal backslash, your input is more fundamentally wrong.

I assume you just have an incorrect expectation, but if that's really *really* what you want, try

```py
# XXX DUBIOUS
line = r'./maryam -e crawl_pages -d domain.tld -r "a href=\\\".*"'
```

which then however looks like this:

```
['./maryam', '-e', 'crawl_pages', '-d', 'domain.tld', '-r', 'a href=\\".*']
```

(because Python prints a double backslash to show a literal backslash).